# Django, Ethereum, Sqlite

Tags: solidity, contract-design, decentralization, database

I am creating blockchain application in django with 6 main entities .By entities I mean to say these 6 entities will replicate data or you can say consensus mechanism will evolve around these entities . Now my question is how can I integrate ethereum in my django app.

I only need ethereum for distributed database storage and my consensus mechanism or proof of work is entirely different as compared to ethereum. Should I use ethereum in my project or completely create it from scratch in sqlite?
I am really confused how to built database for my blockchain application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's very difficult to answer with any precision based on a general description of a modest data model with 6 entities.

Some comments to hopefully help clarify the big topics.

Ethereum **consensus will ensure the correct execution** of a Smart Contract. Within that contract, you can ensure the mission-critical data is dependable. The storage and processing costs are high relative to a relational database because this data will be replicated across all validating nodes; it's immensely redundant.

*In my opinion* the on-chain storage is suitable for a **minimalist storage** that *must be correct* to protect the integrity of the system. A common approach is to record keys and critical information, e.g. users, balances, transaction history, key identifiers, and **document hashes**.

Clients can use the hashes to validate descriptive information and details stored elsewhere. Example, JSON stored elsewhere. A contract points to a location where the details can be discovered and provides a hash of the data stored there.

*In my opinion* contracts should enforce **referential integrity** if the app requires it. That implies primary and foreign keys on chain and some strict rules about permissible updates. Example of how to do referential integrity here: https://medium.com/@robhitchens/enforcing-referential-integrity-in-ethereum-smart-contracts-a9ab1427ff42.

Hope it helps.